# Java method (type, double) returns negative value for large number (not large enough to exceed max value)

Tags: java

I'm pretty new to Java and I wrote a method, `double farey_S(int N)` which works up to N = 10,000, but at N = 100,000 it returns a negative number, as if it overflowed.  But judging by the pattern of outputs:

```
farey_S(10) = 6.914682539682538
farey_S(100) = 58.296238062166246
farey_S(1000) = 517.9547174126604
farey_S(10000) = 5030.839940050789
farey_S(100000) = -8366.231603179493
```

the output shouldn't be *nearly* big enough to exceed the maximum value allowed.

Here is the code:

```
public class InverseCoprimeSum {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        System.out.println("farey_S(10) = " + farey_S(10));
        System.out.println("farey_S(100) = " + farey_S(100));
        System.out.println("farey_S(1000) = " + farey_S(1000));
        System.out.println("farey_S(10000) = " + farey_S(10000));
        System.out.println("farey_S(100000) = " + farey_S(100000));
    }

    public static double farey_S(int N) {
        double tot = 0.0;
        int a, b, a1, b1, c, d, k;
        a = 0;
        b = 1;
        c = 1;
        d = N;
        while(c < N) {
            k = (N + b) / d;
            a1 = a;
            b1 = b;
            a = c;
            b = d;
            c = k * c - a1;
            d = k * d - b1;
            if(a < N - b)
                tot += (a + 1.0) / (a * b);
            else
                tot += (N - b + 1.0) / (a * b);
        }
        tot -= 2;
        return tot;
    }

}
```

Comment: Use a debugger to figure it out.

Comment: Can't `N - b` become negative (or rather less than 1)?

Comment: I strongly suspect this is integer overflow...

Comment: added project-euler tag assuming this is problem #441

Comment: @RC. Yep, it's project euler thanks!

Comment: @user2899059 You mention that the **result** can't be big enough to overflow.  What about all of the intermediate numbers used in the calculation?

Comment: @Sotirios Looking up how to use a debugger

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The multiplication `(a * b)`
is being done as an integer multiplication resulting in an integer overflow.

To be double multiplication, it should be something like

```
        ...
        if(a < N - b)
            tot += (a + 1.0) / ((double)a * b);
        else
            tot += (N - b + 1.0) / ((double)a * b);
        ...
```